# Postgresql less than equal on dates

Tags: postgresql

This looks like a postgresql (v9.4) bug to me, or is this expected behavior?  -- ads with created_at `2015-02-06` are in the table but do not show up in the 2nd query using `<=` operator

```
addb=# select max(created_at)::date from ads;
    max     
------------
 2015-02-06
(1 row)

addb=# SELECT created_at::date, 
       count(*) as num_ads, 
       'created'::text as "activity" 
       FROM ads where created_at>='2015-02-04'::date and 
       created_at<='2015-02-06'::date group by created_at::date;
 created_at | num_ads | activity 
------------+---------+----------
 2015-02-04 |    1153 | created
 2015-02-05 |    1230 | created
(2 rows)
```

Comment: `created_at <= '2015-02-06'::date` will compare timestamps, not dates (i.e. it will search for `created_at <= '2015-02-06 00:00:00'`). use `created_at::date <= '2015-02-06'` instead.

Comment: @pozs good catch, I noticed `created_at::date` won't use my index unless I create a function index to match on the `created_at` column and I also think I'm treading in some dangerious water with timezones, therefor I think I'm going to add 1 day to the end of my range and use a less than operator

Comment: @Kurt yes, you're right, that should work too. you could also add an index too to `(created_at::date)` if you query the date part often.